# I need help constructing a regular expression

Tags: regex

I've been trying to get this sorted out for quite some time.

> Match strings that have even number of `a`s and `b`s and contain substring `aabb`
> defined over `Σ = {a, b}`

For the **regex flavor**, I'm using [regexr](https://www.regexr.com) to build the expression.

I have tried putting the substring between EVEN EVEN but it doesn't work as expected. For example, in even, for:

`(aa|bb|(ab|ba)(aa|bb)*(ab|ba))*(aabb)(aa|bb|(ab|ba)(aa|bb)*(ab|ba))*`

It doesn't work for strings where there are odd number of `a` and `b` before and after the substring. Like for `aaabba`, it doesn't work even though there are four `a` characters.

**Some words of the language would be:**

`aaabba`, `abaabbab`, `aaaabbbaabbb`, `ababaabb`

Comment: Even number of `a` and `b` _in pairs_? `aabb`, `aabbaa`, `aabbaabb`, etc.? And in the other case, odd number of _alternating_ `a` and `b`s? `aba`, `ababa`, `ababab`, etc.?

Comment: Not necessarily, output can be aaabba for the first case. I added some words so you can take a look. Just the total number of a and b in the string must be even in the first case, or odd in the second and must also contain the substrings.

Comment: Well, with .NET regex, I'd use `^(?=.*aabb)(?:(?(o)(?<-o>a)|(?<o>a))|(?(q)(?<-q>b)|(?<q>b)))+$(?(o)(?(q)(?!)))` for the first and `^(?=.*ababab)(?:(?(o)(?<-o>a)|(?<o>a))|(?(q)(?<-q>b)|(?<q>b)))+$(?(o)(?(q)))` for the [second](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.*ababab%29%0d%0a%28%3f%3a%0d%0a%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f%3c-o%3ea%29%7c%28%3f%3co%3ea%29%29%0d%0a%7c%0d%0a%28%3f%28q%29%28%3f%3c-q%3eb%29%7c%28%3f%3cq%3eb%29%29%0d%0a%29%2b%0d%0a%5cr%3f%24%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f%28q%29%29%29&i=aaabba%0d%0aabaabbab%0d%0aaaaabbbaabbb%0d%0aababaabb%0d%0a%0d%0aaabababa%0d%0aababab&o=xm).

Comment: I think you're looking for `evenAoddB aabb evenAoddB | evenAevenB aabb evenAevenB | oddAoddB aabb oddAoddB | oddAevenB aabb oddAevenB`

Comment: To confirm that a string contains an even number of `'a'`'s you can use a positive lookahead: `(?=^[^a]*(?:a[^a]*a[^a]*)*$)`. If there are an even number of `'a'`'s there are an even number of `'b'`'s if and only if the string contains an even number of characters, which we can check with `^(?:[ab]{2})+$`. This also asserts that the string contains no characters other than `'a'` and `'b'`. Putting that together we have `^(?=[^a]*(?:a[^a]*a[^a]*)*$)(?:[ab]{2})+$`. [even](https://regex101.com/r/X6irYp/4/)...

Comment: ...For odd numbers of `'a'`'s and `'b'`'s use `^(?=[^a]*(?:a[^a]*a[^a]*)*a[^a]*$)(?:[ab]{2})+$`. [odd](https://regex101.com/r/X6irYp/5/). If you don't know in advance whether you are looking for even or odd numbers, you can combine the two expressions: `^(?=[^a]*(?:a[^a]*a[^a]*)*$)(?:[ab]{2})+|(?=[^a]*(?:a[^a]*a[^a]*)*a[^a]*$)(?:[ab]{2})+)$`.

Comment: Sketchy, it's an interesting question so I encourage you to edit it in the hopes that it may be re-opened. I suggest you state your question something like the following: "I wish to confirm that a given string contains only the letters `'a'` and `'b'` and there are either even numbers of both `'a'` and `'b'` or odd numbers of both `'a'` and `'b'`.

Comment: By editing, we mean you should 1) narrow the post to **one single problem** (say, match strings with even amont of `b` and `a`s) and 2) state the **regex flavor**.

Comment: regexr supports various regex flavors, JS and PCRE. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=(?:b*ab*a)*b*$)(?=(?:a*ba*b)*a*$)[ab]*aabb[ab]*$
```

See the [JavaScript regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGjSvY/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:b*ab*a)*b*$)` - (even amount of `a` check) up to the end of string, there can be

  - `(?:b*ab*a)*` - 0 or more repetitions of two occurrences of 0 or more `b` chars followed by `a` and then
  - `b*` - zero or more `b` chars
- `(?=(?:a*ba*b)*a*$)` - (even amount of `b` check) up to the end of string, there can be any

  - `(?:a*ba*b)*` - 0 or more repetitions of two occurrences of 0 or more `a` chars followed by `b` and then
  - `a*` - zero or more `a` chars
- `[ab]*` - 0 or more `a` or `b` chars
- `aabb` - a required substring
- `[ab]*` - 0 or more `a` or `b` chars
- `$` - end of string.

*Bonus*: to match the same with odd amount of `a` and `b` chars use

```
^(?=(?:b*ab*a)*b*ab*$)(?=(?:a*ba*b)*a*ba*$)[ab]*aabb[ab]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGjSvY/2)